# Linear Algebra: show $\sum_{m=1}^{M} a_m x_m = 0$ is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem that I can't get my head around.  It says that a is any vector in $\mathbb{F}^M$ and to verify (by the three properties of subspaces) that $\sum_{m=1}^{M} a_{m}x_{m} =0$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^M$.  The zero vector is easy.  The problem I'm having is closed under addition.  Obviously one $x \in \mathbb{F}^M$ is the zero vector (again, easy) and the zero vector is closed under addition with itself and scaler multiplication.  However, what if $a_{1}x_{1} = -a_{2}x_{2}$ for M=2? Does that not also satisfy the sum?  And how do I represent this mathematically for all m?  And then how can I prove that is closed under addition?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Let the set

$$S=\left\{x=(x_1,\ldots,x_M)\in\Bbb F^M,\;\; \sum_{m=1}^M a_mx_m=0\right\}$$

- $S\ne\emptyset$, in fact $0_{\Bbb F^M}\in S$.
- If $x,y\in S$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb F$ then $x+\lambda y\in S$ since:
  $$\sum_{m=1}^M a_m(x_m+\lambda y_m)=\sum_{m=1}^M a_mx_m+\lambda\sum_{m=1}^M a_m y_m=0$$
  so we conclude that $S$ is a subspace of $\Bbb F^M$.

**Remark:** Notice that $S=\langle a\rangle^\perp$ where $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_m)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear. Are you saying: let $a \in \mathbb{F}^{M}$, and $span\{ a \}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^{M}$?

If so, then you would rely on your subspace test that you described.

> > the zero vector is closed under addition with itself and scaler multiplication.

You don't want a single vector closed under the operations. You want *all* elements closed under the operations.

So closure under multiplication is trivial. If we take linear combinations of $a$, then we can only take $ca$, for $c \in \mathbb{F}$. And so we have closure under scalar multiplication. Set $c = 0$ and we have the zero-vector.

By field properties, we know that every constant has an additive inverse. So it is easy to get $ca + -ca = 0$. If we are dealing with a single vector $a \in \mathbb{F}^{M}$, then that's all you have to do to show $span\{ a \}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F}^{M}$.

Comment: I know, it isn't clear to me either.  It just says "Let F be any field and let a be any vector in F^M."  Thank you for the help!

Comment: I think you should accept Sami Ben Romdhane's answer, as it clarifies things. In the future, please try and use proper mathematical notation to clarify your question. I will leave my answer, as it outlines the steps, but Sami interpreted your question better than I was able to.